# Strange switch's behaviour in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

I want the code below to print `ok` when user enters `1` or `3`, or to print `why` otherwise.
**Why, when user enters `3`, the program prints `why`?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    clrscr();
    scanf("%d", &i);
    switch(i){
        case (1||3):
            printf("ok\n");
            break;
        default: 
            printf("why\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you learn that `case(1||3)` is meaningful syntax?

Comment: Btw, this *cannot* be your real, copy/pasted code (unterminated string literal in the scanf line).

Comment: Apart from the typos (`<#include`, etc.), `1 || 3` is a boolean expression. Boolean expressions in C return either `0` or, in this case, `1`.

Comment: Sorry, bro... For my  typos ... And when did i said that it is my copy- pasted code........

Comment: Posts with code that supposedly compile ("whenever I enter 1, the output is "ok"" so something compiled) and then don't compile because of transcriptions errors or whatever are not well received.  As compilable code existed, posting that, rather than a poor copy, would save us all time and prevent aggravation.

Answer (score 4):

```
case(1||3):
```

Will not work. If you want to say "1 or 3", write:

```
case 1 :
case 3 :
    printf("ok");
    break;
```

If you don't have `break` between cases, they flow from one into the next. Try it in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Expression

```
1||3
```

has constant value 1. Operator || is the logical OR operator that according to the C Standard

> 3 The || operator **shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0**; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So if you enter 1 then code under the case label will be executed. Otherwise the code under the default label is executed.

In fact your switch statement looks like

```
   switch(i)
         {
              case 1:
                            printf("ok");
                            break;
             default: 
                           printf("why");
          }
```

Expression 1 || 3 will be calculated at compilation time and the compiler will generate code that will correspond to the label

```
case 1:
```

All case label expressions are evaluated at compilation time and instead of the expressions the compiler uses their results.

To achive the result you want you should either add one more case label or substitute the switch statement for a if-else statement. For example

```
   switch(i)
         {
              case 1:
              case 3:
                            printf("ok");
                            break;
             default: 
                           printf("why");
          }
```

or

```
   if( i == 1 || i == 3 )
   {
       printf("ok");
   }
   else
   {
        printf("why");
   }
```

Comment: i didn't get it " if either operands compare  unequal to 0". Isn't 3 not equal to True? I mean why it is only working with 1 but not with 3.

Comment: @Rooparsh Kalia The value of the expression 1 || 3 is 1. The expression is evaluayted at compilation time before you will execute the program. So the compiler will generate code that is equivalent to case 1:

Comment: `3` is evaluated as `true`, but don't have to be equal to `true` - usually, `true` is `1`

Comment: if the value of 1 ||3 is 1 , then why doesn't it always print ok, even if i enter 4

Comment: @Rooparsh Kalia 4 is not equal to 1. Expression 1 || 3 has integer type and value 1.

Comment: @ Vlad  ... can u please explain how expression is evaluated at run time , and what does it have to do with 3...am just not getting ur point

Comment: @Rooparsh Kalia At compilation time the compiler evaluates all case expressions and substitutes them for their results. So you will have case 1: because the value of expression 1 || 3 is equal to 1. So when expression in the switch is evaluated when you entered 3 it is compared with the value of the case label that is equal to 1. As 1 is not equal to 3 then the control is passed to the default label.

Comment: I'd consider upvoting if the code indentation wasn't horrid.

Answer (score 2):

You want to learn the following paradigm for flow control:

```
switch(i)
{
    case (1):
    case (3):
        printf("ok");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("why");
}
```

Where either 1 or 3 will fall through until the break.

1||3 => true... which is typically 0x1

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
printf( (i==1||i==3)?"ok":"why" );
```

Comment: i know this approach.... but i want to learn the reason why my snippet of code is code... and ur code should be like printf( if((i==1) || (i==3))?"ok":"why" );

Comment: Code you gave in the comment won't compile; it seems you confuse `if` with `?:`